# Broken ssl in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

Chrome (on Win and Linux) was unable to load https://apscatalog.com.

Though all other browsers and Chrome on Mac was able to load site with no warnings or errors.

Even external tools say that everything is fine: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=apscatalog.com

How can I fix this issue?

**Update**
It seems to be a Chrome bug. Chrome v.33 works fine while v.32 fails

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that the they have some broken appliance (firewall, load balancer...) in front of it. From wireshark I see the Client Hello from Chrome, but it never gets a response, not even an ACK that the packet was received. That's why it's retransmitting the Client Hello again and again until it finally gives up. I've seen such problems with older F5 BIG-IP load balancers (it's fixed in the meantime, but there are still some broken ones out there) but this does not seem to be the case here. So it's probably yet another broken appliance :(

In case you have knowledge of the infrastructure there I would really like to know what device this might be.

Comment: I doubt this problem related to the hardware because I've got another site on this machine and its https works fine.

Comment: I think it is not a problem on the server itself, because there is no TCP ACK for the Client Hello packet. But the ACK is sent by the OS once it received the packet, no matter if there are problems at the application level. You might try a tcpdump/wireshark on the server itself, but I would assume that the server does not get the Client Hello at all because some appliance in front of the server (or some packet filter at the server itself) filters it away.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that https://apscatalog.com works if chrome is started with ssl-version-max=tls1:

google-chrome --ssl-version-max=tls1

Comment: Please use a comment if it don't really answer the question.